# How to add Mask to a monadic stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to use the bracket function from Exception.Safe Package which has a return type of

```
forall m a b c. MonadMask m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> m c
```

This implies that my monad stack must have the Mask monad added to the stack ? 
My calling function looks like this

```
sendMessage :: String -> Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())
sendMessage msg=do
      getProperties <- producerProps
      let
        mkProducer =  newProducer getProperties
        clProducer (Left _)     = return ()
        clProducer (Right prod) = closeProducer prod
        runHandler (Left err)   = return $ Left err
        runHandler (Right prod) = messageSender prod msg
      res <- bracket mkProducer clProducer runHandler
      return res
```

And config.KakfaP has the type

```
ReaderT ProducerConfig IO a
```

And the error I get is ,

```
No instance for (exceptions-0.10.0:Control.Monad.Catch.MonadMask
                         Config.KafkaP)
        arising from a use of ‘bracket’
```

Does this mean the monad stack needs to be something like this

```
Mask (ReaderT ProducerConfig IO a)
```

Ideally I would want the function to return what the run Handler returns which is Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ()) ,or anything more robust .

Adding a solution based on an answer

```
sendMessage :: String -> Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())
sendMessage msg=do
      getProperties <- producerProps
      let
        mkProducer =  newProducer getProperties  
        --newProducer :: MonadIO m => ProducerProperties -> m (Either KafkaError KafkaProducer)
        --mkProducer :: Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError KafkaProducer)
        clProducer (Left _)     = return ()
        clProducer (Right prod) = closeProducer prod
        --closeProducer :: MonadIO m => KafkaProducer -> m ()
        --clProducer :: Config.KafkaP (Either () ())  -- ?? 
        runHandler (Left err)   = return $ Left err
        runHandler (Right prod) = messageSender prod msg
        --messageSender :: KafkaProducer -> String -> Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())
        --runHandler :: Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ()) -- ?? 
      Config.KafkaP $ bracket (Config.runK  mkProducer) (Config.runK .clProducer) (Config.runK .runHandler)
```

Comment: MonadMask isn't a monad or monad transformer like Either(T), Maybe(T), etc. It's a typeclass, like Monad itself, MonadFail, etc.

Comment: So I used another function which had a typeconstraint of MonadIO m , so that would mean m has the the type IO or part of a stack which has IO right ?   Isnt it the same case for MonadMask ?

Comment: Yes, MonadIO is a typeclass just like MonadMask is. Note that MonadIO and IO are not the same thing, though, and the latter is not a typeclass.

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya Is `KakfaP` a type synonym, or is it defined using a newtype?

Comment: @danidiaz it is defined as a newtype

Comment: @JosephSible Iam still confused as to the difference between the two

Comment: `IO` is a type (well, type constructor, anyway). `MonadIO` and `MonadMask` are both type classes for which there are `IO` instances defined. (`instance MonadIO IO where ...` and `instance MonadMask IO where ... `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using the type `ReaderT ProducerConfig IO a` directly, there wouldn't be a problem, because the [exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) package provides an instance

> MonadMask IO

That says you can use `bracket` with `IO`, and another instance

> MonadMask m => MonadMask (ReaderT r m)

That says that if the base monad is an instance of `MonadMask`, then `ReaderT` over that monad is also an instance of `MonadMask`.

Notice that `MonadMask` is not a transformer that is part of the monad stack. Instead, it is a constraint that says "this monad stack supports masking / bracketing operations".

---

If you were using a [type synonym](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym) like

```
type KafkaP a = ReaderT ProducerConfig IO a
```

there wouldn't be a problem either, because type synonyms don't create a new type, they just give an alias to an exiting one. One can still make use of all the existing typeclass instances for the type.

---

You mention in the comments that `KafkaP` is a newtype. A newtype is a cheap way of creating, well, a *new type* out of another. It's basically a constructor that holds a value of the original type.

And that's the problem. Because it is a new type, it doesn't share automatically all the typeclass instances of the old one. In fact, having *different* typeclass instances in newtypes is one of the main motivations for using newtypes!

What can be done? Well, supposing the newtype constructor is exported (sometimes they are hidden for purposes of encapsulation) you could unwrap the `KafkaP`s actions into `ReaderT ProducerConfig IO a` before sending them into `bracket`, and then re-wrap the result into `KafkaP` again. Some of the parameters are `KafkaP`-returning functions, so you'll probably need to throw in some function composition as well. Perhaps something like (assuming `KafkaP` is the name of the constructor, and `runKafkaP` the name of the corresponding accessor):

```
KafkaP $ bracket (runKafkaP mkProducer) (runKafkaP . clProducer) (runKafkaP . runHandler)
```

All this wrapping and unwrapping is tedious; sometimes using [`coerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) from `Data.Coerce` can help. But this only works when the newtype constructor is exported.

---

You might also think of defining your own `MonadMask` instance for `KafkaP` using the technique above. This can be done, but instances which are defined neither in the module that defines the typeclass nor in the module that defines the type are called [orphan instances](https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance) and are somewhat frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a well explained answer. I implemented the changes , and have added the code . Just wanted to understand , why is the composition operator needed for the clProducer and runHandler  and not for mkProducer , as all three functions are returning values wrapped in Config.KafkaP . I have mentioned the types of the functions called ,and what I think are the types for the variables in the let statment

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya `mkProducer` has type `Config.KafkaP x`, so the newtype can be unwrapped directly. `clProducer`  and `runHandler` are *functions* of the form `x -> Config.KafkaP y`. Here what we must unwrap is the *return value* of the function. And working over the return value of a function with another function is exactly what function composition does.

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya In case you want to define your own `MonadMask` instance for `KafkaP`, the `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving` extension can be helpful. It lets you auto-derive typeclass instances for your newtype, by "piggybacking" on already existing instances of the wrapped type. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes